# Short apt sources list on Xenial

Tags: apt, updates, 16.04

I have two computers. One running 16.04 (installed a few days before the actual release). The other running 14.04. When I do `sudo apt update` on 14.04, I get a long list of sources being updated (about 70 or 80). When I run the same command on 16.04 I only get  10 hits:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.accretive-networks.net/ubuntu xenial InRelease            
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:4 http://mirrors.accretive-networks.net/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease    
Hit:5 http://mirrors.accretive-networks.net/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease  
Hit:6 http://mirrors.accretive-networks.net/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease   
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/ppa-kicad/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
```

Is this expected? Am I missing any repositories because I installed a pre-release version of Xenial?

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you posted the output of the 14.04 machine too and the number of PPAs you installed. Basically there were major changes in apt in this release, appstream was integrated and the Ubuntu Software Center was deprecated. One side effect is that the long list you had in the past is now a bit shorter, you will notice for example that lines  containing  "translation" don't appear in the output anymore. This is just an observation, I haven't found the corresponding page with details that explains all the changes to read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably added some ppas to your  14.04 machine's sources in the past.

You could compare /etc/apt/sources.list files and /etc/apt/sources.list.d directories to get more information on this.